# Service that uses libcurl not auto-starting on Debian?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, debian, init.d

I've written and compiled a daemon program in C which is meant to run in the background with root access. My program uses libcurl to make some occasional network calls. I've also written a simple init.d script to govern its startup and shutdown procedures. I would like this service to automatically start on boot, and based on what I've done I would expect it to already be doing this. However, I'm noticing an error in the logs relating to libcurl, and as a result the service is not being started automatically.

My program is located in `/usr/bin/myprog` and I have the following bash script located in `/etc/init.d/myprog`:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: myprog
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start: 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: myprog
# Description: My Daemon Program
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

SCRIPT=/usr/bin/myprog
PIDFILE=/var/run/myprog.pid

start() {
    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
        echo "Service is already started"
        return 2
    else
        $SCRIPT
        $RETVAL="$?"
        return "${RETVAL}"
    fi
}

stop() {
    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
        kill $(cat $PIDFILE)
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        return 0
    else
        echo "Service is not running"
        return 2
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting myprog" "myprog"
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping myprog" "myprog"
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        status_of_proce "$SCRIPT" "myprog" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    restart)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting myprog" "myprog"
        stop
        start
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

I then ran `sudo update-rc.d myprog defaults` and this created the following files:

- /etc/rc0.d/K01myprog
- /etc/rc1.d/K01myprog
- /etc/rc2.d/K01myprog
- /etc/rc3.d/S02myprog
- /etc/rc4.d/S02myprog
- /etc/rc5.d/S02myprog
- /etc/rc6.d/K01myprog

And as far as I can tell, each of those 7 files are identical copies of the one I posted above. Based on the various tutorials and forums I've been reading, I would think this would be sufficient. However, my service does not appear to be auto-starting on boot. If I call `sudo /etc/init.d/myprog start` directly, then it starts up fine. But otherwise it does not appear to be launched.

I then noticed an error message in the logs which said "curl error: could not resolve host," even though the particular host it was referencing was definitely valid. So I think perhaps it's trying to launch my application before something that libcurl needs is ready, and is therefore failing to launch. Again, if I launch it manually it works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should use `dmesg|grep "curl"` and post what the actual error is.

Comment: The message is "Could not resolve host: www.xxxxxx.com" Here I'm censoring the actual domain because it's something for work and I don't want to share the URL, but suffice it to say that URL definitely is valid. Which is only further confirmed by the fact that I can run this same program manually and then it works.

Comment: Also that message came from my own logs (because I'm setting CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER and logging on failures); when I ran the dmesg command you suggested it just came back blank.

Answer (score 0):

If DNS resolution is the point of failure then use the IP address instead. If you are unwilling to use the IP address, add the hostname and IP address to /etc/hosts.

Comment: But I don't believe DNS resolution is truly the point of failure, based on the fact that I can run the same code manually and then it works fine. It seems as if it's trying to run it too early and the underlying systems are not ready for DNS resolution (or whatever else) yet.

Comment: It is easy enough to try my suggestion and know for sure.

Comment: This isn't practical in a business situation when you consider that the DNS resolves to an Amazon server and so the IP may change regularly.